# Should you target popular (i.e competitive) keywords as a small website?

Tags: seo, blog

I am now writing articles for blog posts on a website that is about to be launched in a very competitive space (dating advice). It is very unlikely we will get the links necessary to compete on popular keywords such as "how to get a girlfriend".

Does that mean targeting popular keywords is not good for a new website? Should my blog posts only target long tail keywords no big site is competing with me on?

Comment: While its a good thing to rank for tail long keywords I don't advise writing your content with that objective. Your content should be written for users not search engines. Interaction from users is key to  long-term success. Articles that fail to grab audience in and interact with it, sends all the wrong signals to search engines.

Comment: @SimonHayter I would like however to know if I may do stuff that would cause no users to visit my site. After knowing it I could continue writing in peace :)

Comment: I am not sure, however, my answer to your last question may clarify things. Or confuse them. Who knows? I always suggest not going where the waters are deep. There are too many sharks. Instead, go where you can stand out... you know... where the girls are. ;-) Cheers!!

Comment: If you stood in Madison Square Garden full to the rafters with people all shouting essentially the same thing and you shout much the same, how could you be heard? If, however, you go Central Park and speak words of contrarianism and wisdom, could you then be heard? Channeling my very best Frank Zappa when he sings "Watch out where the huskies go..." I say, "Watch out where the lemmings go..." [humor]

Answer (score 3):

Wow.  What a fun gig.  Congratulations!

I'd have a field day with this.  So much potential.

If you are in a competitive niche, then make your content localised. e.g. "How/where to meet a girl/boy/friend in xxx" location.

You can still target the competitive search terms, but results will be for your local area.

Also offer articles on related topics like wardrobe/appearance/makeup/scents/perfume, choosing a date restaurant, movie, picnic, park, etc.

this will also give your web site the chance to "monetise" with affiliate links or  advertising for local businesses, if that's part of your strategy.

The opportunities are endless.

Hope this helps.  Good luck.